# Add/Remove Application part to kestrel at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is it possible to add/remove [application parts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-2.2) at runtime?

We have about 800 Web API's which share the same common infrastructural code. End result is actually a dll that wouldn't have any conflict with any other dll.

So I was looking into loading and unloading multiple project deployable dlls to a single kestrel app server.

Any ideas?

Comment: _So I was looking into loading and unloading multiple project deployable dlls_ Unloading of Assemblies isn't yet supported in .NET Core. It's planed for .NET Core 3.0 and available in its preview 2. See [this Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/19773#issuecomment-434520417) for hints how to load/unload assemblies with .NET Core 3.0 preview2. No idea about unloading application parts

Comment: Only loading doesn't make lots of sense though. How  do I update a dll to a new version?

Comment: See the provided GitHub comment please. It shows how to load and unload... assemblies that is. Basically you have to load the assemblies within a `AssemblyLoadContext` and then unload the **context** (which unloads **all** assemblies loaded in this `AssemblyLoadContext`). Simply unloading a single assembly isnt possible (wasn't possible in .NET Framework neither, there you did load the assemblies in `AppDomain` and unload the whole domain. But .NET Core doesn't have the concept of `AppDomain's anymore)

Comment: Dis u find something on the subject?

Comment: I think there are some possibilities in .net core 3.0 but no concrete examples.